# node repl showing error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam a newbie to node.js and when I tried to run the Hello world application it showed error.I created a main.js file and using node repl i called the $ node main.js.It resulted in error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:221:25)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

After that I tried the same with normal command prompt.I traversed to main.js and executed node main.js then it showed the output.But in examples, the JS is executed using the node repl.Its totally confusing.If I try $ node in repl it also shows error. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute `node main.js` at your OS command/shell prompt, not the node repl.

Comment: ok i got that ...when i tried  $ node in repl it showed the same error.Is it like that?

Comment: The REPL is for executing javascript, not executing commands (well, short of the few special REPL commands that start with a `.`) or external scripts.